# Django REST Framework requires hashed password to login

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Django requires me to send a hashed password to get my JWT token. When I send the following request via postman I get a "CustomUser matching query does not exist" error.

```
{

   "user": {
       "email": "myuser",
       "password": "mypassword"

   }
}
```

I can, however, run the code with the hashed password (after looking it up from the admin) and it returns the correct value. How do I send unhashed passwords or hash the passwords before I send them?

I am using a custom user model that substitutes email for username. I've tried pointing my code to the header using `request.META.get("username")` and `request.META.get("password")` but I receive a 'field required' error. I've also tried to figure out how to hash the password on the app before sending it to my API, but I have failed to find a method that works.

I have my view below for handling the request.

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password') 
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide your username and password'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(email=username, password=password)

    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

I expected to get a JWT token but instead have either  got "CustomUser matching query does not exist" or "field required"

EDIT ----- Adding my custom model ---

```
import jwt

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
)
from django.db import models

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):

        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Superusers must have a password')

        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):

        return self.username

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):

        dt = datetime.now()
        expr = dt + timedelta(days=60)
        dtt = int(expr.timestamp())
        token = jwt.encode({
            'id':self.pk,
            'exp': dtt,
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
        return token.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Shouldn't you get username via `request.data.get('email')` and call `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`?

Comment: When I do  that and pass the following JSON package I still get the "Matching Query" issue.
`{
 
 "user": {
  "email": "me@mysite.com",
        "username": "myuser",
  "password": "mypass"
     
 }
}`

Comment: are you using custom auth backend?
because django should hash the passwords not you in the frontend
if you don't please add your custom user model so we can help you better

Comment: @mmoallemi99 I added the custom user model above.

Comment: @Squ3lchr add your UserManager class too

Comment: @MMoallemi99 It was added above the CustomUser model in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. In implementing JWT I left Django's default version authentication online. I decided to remove JWT en lieu of reworking everything. It works perfectly now.